# Python ignore Null value from CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, null

```
with open('zim.csv','r') as luck:
reader = csv.reader(luck)
with open('dib.csv','w', newline='') as waffles:
   writer = csv.writer(waffles)
   for line in reader:
```

I'm reading a csv with 4 colums of data.  Column 3 has nulls in the first 3 rows.  What i want is to read that it's null, ignore it, and move on processing.  I've tried try-except after this for statement, but i realized processing is stopped at for statement.  Any help?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend using `pandas`.

Comment: Hey, it worked!